# BizTalk HL7 Receive Pipeline Unable to configure logstore -- SQL server error

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, btahl7, biztalk-2013

I've recently installed the BizTalk 2013 HL7 adapter on my development machine. During setup, it asks for the logging account, which I provided and was successfully added and the installation finished without a hitch.

However, when I try to submit a message to the Receive port configured to use the HL7 pipeline, I'm always receiving the same errors

First there is an "Information" event log stating:

> Login failed for user '**my-BizTalk-HOST-account**'. Reason: Failed to open
>   the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 1.2.3.4]

Then immediately after there is:

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "BTAHL72XPipelines.BTAHL72XReceivePipeline, BTAHL72XPipelines, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "BTAHL7 2.X Disassembler" Receive Port: "my-receive-port-name" URI: "0.0.0.0:11001" Reason: Unable to configure the logstore.

If I look at the details tab in the event, it shows in the Binary Data in Bytes, the name of my server, followed by master.

A few points to consider:

- we do not have SQL Server logging enabled in the HL7 configuration
  tool (just the event log)
- **my-BizTalk-HOST-account** is not the account that is configured for HL7 logging anyway, so why is it being used?
- I'm not sure why it's trying to access the master database (if that is indeed what the event log is telling me)
- SQL logins/users for **my-BizTalk-HOST-account** are setup in the BizTalk databases with proper permissions
- sending to any other receive location behaves fine, it's just those using the BTAHL72xReceivePipeline

Can anyone explain this or have a fix?

Comment: Run SQL profiler on the database server and see what database it is trying to access.

Comment: Thanks @Dijkgraaf I did that and it made me realize I'm a complete buffoon. I was logged into SQL Server Management Studio on the wrong server! Man, I feel like a fool.

Comment: No worries, good that you manage to resolve it.